# Cannot find type definition file for 'ramda'

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ramda.js

I have a project with `Ionic` 2 & `Angular` 2.

I use RamdaJS in my code, this is perfectly working with these commands:

- `ionic serve`
- `ionic cordova build android`
- `ionic cordova run android`

But when I try to execute this command: `ionic cordova build android --prod --release`, I got an error about Ramda and Type.

See a part of my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "3.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "3.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.16",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "ionic-angular": "2.3.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "material-design-icons": "3.0.1",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "moment-duration-format": "1.3.0",
    "ng2-translate": "5.0.0",
    "ng2-webstorage": "1.5.1",
    "ngx-pipes": "1.5.7",
    "ramda": "0.23.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2",
    "cordova-android": "~7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.2.2",
    "@types/ramda": "github:types/npm-ramda",
    "@types/moment-duration-format": "1.3.1",
    "typescript": "2.2.1"
  }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths" : {
       "ramda": [
         "location-of-types/npm-ramda-package/index"
       ]
     },
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Error when trying to build for production:

```
[12:26:31]  typescript error
            Cannot find type definition file for 'ramda'.

Error: Failed to transpile TypeScript
```

Comment: not sure if this is the issue but you only need type defs in dev.. try to reeinstall as dev-dependencies and try

Comment: @SurajRao about this point, you're right! I've move types dep in dev dependencies. Unfortunately, it didn't solve build issue

Comment: In the tsconfig file you posted, it says `location-of-types/npm-ramda-package/index`. Dumb question, but did you replace it with the correct types folder in your real code?

Comment: That's not a dumb question, I didn't.. Correct path would be `node_modules/@types` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the types via `@types/packageName` as recommended by [**DefinitlyTyped**](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

For NPM do:

```
npm install @types/ramda --save-dev
```

For YARN use:

```
yarn add @types/ramda --dev
```

Typescript looks by default for a directiory named `@types` inside your `node_modules` to find type definitions:

> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/, ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.
>
> If typeRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included.

[**tsconfig.json docs**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I got the same error.. Updating my answer with tsconfig and part of package.json

Comment: Is the DefinitelyTyped version identical to npm-ramda? There's an github issue about it, but I couldn't figure out if this is resolved or not. https://github.com/types/npm-ramda/issues/163

Answer (score 1):

Follow the install instructions here: https://github.com/types/npm-ramda

> ```
> # using npm
> npm install --save-dev types/npm-ramda#dist
> ```
>
> If not using npm/yarn, you may need to add these typings to paths in
>   tsconfig.json:
>
> For the full package:
>
> ```
> {
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "baseUrl": "./",
>     "paths" : {
>        "ramda": [
>          "location-of-types/npm-ramda-package/index"
>        ]
>      }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I got the same error.. Updating my answer with tsconfig and part of package.json

Comment: `location-of-types/npm-ramda-package/index` is a placeholder, you should try use `@types/ramda/index`

Comment: this is not working, was it removed from npm registry?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you can ask the library maintainer by filing an issue on GitHub. https://github.com/types/npm-ramda